# ACF Gallery - Show 4 items at a time using Bootstrap 4

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm using a *Gallery* field in WordPress ACF and I want to show a gallery only *four* at a time. Therefore, to achieve this, I grabbed some [code](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/exVWQ) for a multi-carousel in Bootstrap 4 and wanted to achieve this same effect using ACF Gallery and PHP.

Here's my code attempt:

```
            <div class="row blog">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="blogCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                        [...]

                        <!-- Carousel items -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner">

                            <?php
                                $images = get_sub_field('gallery');
                                $i = 0;
                                $j = 0;
                                $internal_counter = 0;
                            ?>

                            <?php while ( $i < $gallery_size ): ?>
                                <?php if ( $i % 4 === 0 ): ?>
                                    <div class="carousel-item <?php if ( $internal_counter === 0 ): echo 'active'; endif; ?>">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            // BEGIN this is the part where i'm stuck on
                                            <?php for ( $j = 0; $j < count ( $images ); $j++ ): ?>
                                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                                    <a href="<?php echo $images[$j]['url']; ?>" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="dayhome-gallery">
                                                        <img src="<?php echo $images[$j]['sizes']['large']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $images[$j]['alt']; ?>" />
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                            <?php endfor; ?>
                                            // END this is the part where i'm stuck on
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php $internal_counter++; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php $i++; ?>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

I've highlighted in comments above where I'm stuck on. Right now it's just displaying 8 pictures at a time for each carousel item such as this picture below:

[image]

Here's the desired effect I want:

[image]

So, in this particular gallery, I want to show only *four* pictures at a time. I was thinking of performing something like this:

```
<?php
  if ( $j % 4 === 0 ):
    break;
  endif;
?>
```

... but it breaks immediately because I started `$j` to be 0 because I also need the zeroth item in the gallery.

Thanks for any help with my code.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!!

```
<div class="carousel-item <?php if ( $internal_counter === 0 ): echo 'active'; endif; ?>">
    <div class="row">
        <?php while ( $j < count( $images ) ): ?>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="<?php echo $images[$j]['url']; ?>" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="dayhome-gallery">
                    <img src="<?php echo $images[$j]['sizes']['large']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $images[$j]['alt']; ?>" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <?php if ( ++$j % 4 === 0 ): ?>
                <?php break; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I had to make sure I put `++$j` to pre-iterate my variable before comparing it to a modulus of 4.